# Restart httpd after changes in the httpd.conf

Tags: apache, apache-config

Do I need to restart httpd after changes in the httpd.conf file for changes to take effect?

Comment: @svisstack true, but apache and apache-config is not related to programming either.

Comment: this should be asked on serverfault.com not stackoverflow.com, on serverfault you will get better results, on stackoverflow is not for peoples who interesting with this things.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes.
HTTPD.conf is read on apache start-up, so for any changes to take affect you need to restart it.

Comment: You can do `service httpd reload`, so apache will not be down.

Comment: @narkoz service does not exist so useing /etc/init.d/httpd status/restart

Comment: I did a redirect, but restarting also does not solve the issue...what could be wrong.  I have logged in as root.

Comment: If your changes are not taking effect after restart, it is possible that your httpd.conf is incorrect.

Comment: Jean, `/etc/init.d/httpd reload`

Comment: Are the certificate changes in ssl.conf also picked up by reload of httpd ?

Comment: @vishnu Yes, it should be.

Answer (score 8):

Yes you need to restart the server by

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

You can check errors in your config files by

```
apachectl -t
```

Changes may take some time to reflect.

Comment: You can do a graceful restart which does not require "restart the server" @Raghunandan J

Answer (score 3):

You can have apache re-read its config files without restarting by
`sudo apachectl graceful` (or `apache2ctl` on debian).

From the [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/apachectl.html):

> Gracefully restarts the Apache httpd daemon. If the daemon is not running, it is started. This differs from a normal restart in that currently open connections are not aborted. [...] This command automatically checks the configuration files as in configtest before initiating the restart to make sure Apache doesn't die.